# How to do slope comparison in SPSS?

Tags: spss

I have data from density rearing. Organism was reared in several different densities and the number of surviving individuals was counted once a week for four weeks.

My aim is to spesify what would be suitable rearing density. I was asked to do a slope comparison; **the highest density for which the slope does not differ from the flat line** will be considered as the threshold density.

The question is: How to do this in SPSS?

If I have understood right, I should do some sort of univariate test. But how to organize the data? In the experiment there was several replicates and blocks. Should I first count mean of alive individuals for each density at certain measurement time? To what do I compare each slope in the test?

Comment: This is not a site for SPSS questions, and the analytical attach you described is not recommended because it is based on arbitrary statistical significance.  Instead consider something like a simultaneous confidence bands for slopes as a function of density.